# Jackson android NPE when use MixIn

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jackson

My server api uses polymorphic objects of different types. For example, I have a json:

```
{
  "eventType": "FirstType",
  "eventData": "some-useful-object"
}
```

and kotlin class for it:

```java
sealed class NotificationEvent {

  data class SomeUsefulEvent(val eventData: String): NotificationEvent()

}
```

and mixin class:

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "eventType"
)
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(
        value = NotificationEvent.SomeUsefulEvent::class,
        name = "FirstType"
    )
)
abstract class NotificationEventMixIn
```

when I call from client side

```java
jsonMapper.readValue<NotificationEvent>(event.data)
```

the application crashes with NPE:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null
>   object reference
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector._addFieldMixIns(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:110)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector._findFields(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:87)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector.collect(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:41)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector.collectFields(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:36)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass._fields(AnnotatedClass.java:349)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.fields(AnnotatedClass.java:321)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addFields(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:379)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collectAll(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:308)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getPropertyMap(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:287)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getProperties(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:170)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription._properties(BasicBeanDescription.java:164)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.findProperties(BasicBeanDescription.java:239)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._findCreatorsFromProperties(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:346)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._constructDefaultValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:330)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:255)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:214)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:137)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:411)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:349)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:477)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:4178)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3997)
>           at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3011)

how can I avoid this crash?

Comment: Great job, but in case you already found answer for this problem remove answer from question and put it as answer below. It will be much easier to find it.

Comment: @MichałZiober updated. Actually, it's not an answer - it's a workaround. It looks weird and hacky. Moreover, it works differently on different devices and it's kinda weird. That's why my "answer" will not be marked as correct one and I'll wait for fasterxml team to fix it or explain how to use this feature correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some amount of time wasted on research I found that in `AnnotatedFieldCollector#_findFields` there is `for` block which calls `JavaType.getRawClass().getDeclaredFields()` and if it returns an empty array, all the `for` block is skipped, map `_fields` is not initialized and stays `null` when `_addFieldMixIns` is called.

This happens because properties are not fields in kotlin and parent class does not have one.

This issue can be workarounded by adding `@JvmField` annotated property to `NotificationEvent` class like this:

```java
sealed class NotificationEvent {

  @Suppress("unused")
  @JvmField val stub: Int = 0

  data class SomeUsefulEvent(val eventData: String): NotificationEvent()

}
```

and everything works fine!

I hope this question will help somebody and I encourage Jackson team to fix this bug